# Подскажите по Lazarus

Tags: lazarus

Извините за риторический вопрос - кто из Вас работал на Lazarus? Интересно мнение коллег. Особенно по доступу к MySQL. Также интересует доступ к OpenOffice или к генераторам отчетов (хотя никто не отменял HTML). И, естественно, по-поводу кроссплатформености. Спасибо за ответы.

Comment: >Извините за риторический вопрос

почему риторический-то?

Comment: Ну такое выражение:)

Comment: вероятно, вы не очень понимаете смысл этого выражения. Поскольку оно означает "вопрос, не требующий ответа"

Comment: Да, Вы правы. Не правильно сформулировал.

Answer (score 1):

ZEOS DB вроде бы кросс-платформенна, там ещё встроенные средства доступа к БД есть. Установить да посмотреть - ничего не мешает=)

Comment: Спасибо. С Zeos знаком по Delphi. А генератор отчетов не знаете? Просто заказана программа, к которой не должны придраться соотв. органы - т.е. полностью Free.

Comment: У FastReport введена поддержка Lazarus. На счет кросс-платформенности у него, не знаю.

Comment: Спасибо. Посмотрю.